# Symfony Fos User login

Tags: symfony

I installed Fos User Bundle from tutorial step by step and I have a problem because when I try get to 127.0.0.1:8000/login there is an error "AppBundle\Entity\Car object not found.". When I check logs there is a message "Matched route "car_details"." when I think it should be "fos_user_security_login". How can I fix this?

Routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Ok, I know where the problem is. There is a function in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="samochod_detale")
 *
 * @param Samochod $samochod
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function detaleAction(Samochod $samochod)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl("samochod_usun", ["id" => $samochod->getId()]))
        ->setMethod(Request::METHOD_DELETE)
        ->add("submit", SubmitType::class, ["label" => "Usuń pojazd"])
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render("samochod/detale.html.twig", ["samochod" => $samochod, "deleteForm" => $deleteForm->createView()]);
}
```

So login is matched as {id}, but I don't know why. Register works only if the address has a slash at the end like /register/, login doesn't work even with that.

Comment: Can you show your routing?

Answer (score 0):

Set fos_user rule first in routing.yml:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
...
```